# Climbing the leaderboard on HackerRank

Tags: c++, algorithm

I know, there are a lot of questions like this, but I want to see other's solutions only after solving this (https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/climbing-the-leaderboard/problem). Here's my code:

```
vector<int> climbingLeaderboard(vector<int> ranked, vector<int> player) {
    vector<int> ranked_new; // the same ranked but without repeating numbers
    vector<int> ans; // vector with places
    
    // filling ranked_new
    for (int i = 1; i < ranked.size(); i++)
    { if (ranked[i] != ranked[i - 1]) ranked_new.push_back(ranked[i]); }
    ranked_new.insert(ranked_new.begin(), ranked[0]);

    int left = 0, right = ranked_new.size() - 1, mid;
    bool flag;
    
    // binary searching for place for every Alice's result
    for (int i = 0; i < player.size(); i++)
    {
        flag = false; left = 0; right = ranked_new.size() - 1;
        while (!(flag))
        {
            if (player[i] >= ranked_new[0]) { flag = true; ans.push_back(0); }
            else if (player[i] <= ranked_new[ranked_new.size() - 1]) { flag = true; ans.push_back(ranked_new.size()); }
            else
            {
                mid = (left + right) / 2;
                if (left >= right) { flag = true; ans.push_back(left); }
                else if (player[i] > ranked_new[mid]) { right = mid - 1; }
                else { left = mid + 1; }
            }
        }
    }

    // increasing every ans element by one
    for(int i = 0; i < ans.size(); i++) { ans[i]++; }
    return ans;
}
```

It passed 0, 5, 8 and 11 tests. In tests which it didn't pass repeats one error. For example, in test 1:

```
88
88
87
85
84
84
83
82
```

but my code returns

```
88
88
88
85
84
84
82
82
```

This is the only bug, I think it's somewhere in binary search but I still can't understand how to fix it. Please can you give me a hint?

EDIT: here are my attempts

In controversial situations (like player[i] == ranked_new[some_index]) program disbehaves (for example in test 1 when it gives 88 88 88 instead of 88 88 87). So I thought I should edit the string

```
if (left >= right) { flag = true; ans.push_back(left); }
```

with this code

```
if (left >= right) 
{
if (player[i] > left) {flag = true; ans.push_back(left - 1);}
else if (player[i] < left) {flag = true; ans.push_back(left + 1);}
else {flag = true; ans.push_back(left);
}
```

But I was wrong and it didn't work. Sample test case output: 6 4 2 1. My output: 6 3 1 1 (I tried to change left with right, swap them, swapped + and -, changed numbers but it works only if it pushes back "left" in any case). I have chosen 1 case when it outputs 6 5 3 1, changed code, set left to 1, etc. to decrement numbers between 6 and 1 but it still didn't work on the same tests. I thought about it for 1,5 days and then came to stackoverflow

Comment: Your question's title does not describe the question.

Comment: "but I want to see other's solutions only after solving this" you notice that you *are* asking others to provide you a solution? What else is the question?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to pin the link to the question

Comment: Are you talking about changing your ranking on HackerRank?  Or, is this program about changing ranks?

Comment: No, this is the name of the problem on the site

Comment: I'm not looking for a solution, but just for a hint. I tried a couple of things, but they didn't work and now I don't understand how to fix this, where to look for an error

Comment: Please edit your post with the results of your debugging session.  For example, which statement is causing the issue.  What are the expected values of the variables?  What are the actual values of variables?

Comment: Ok, give me 10 mins

Comment: You should only use binary search if the container is sorted.  Print out the container before you sort, to verify that the container is sorted.  (You may want to write code to verify that the container is sorted, before you search.)

Comment: Try to use C++ [standard algorithms](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) whenever you can instead of writing your own from scratch.

Comment: @АлександрII I tried that problem and wrote [this code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ab623098d2f5e1db), it passes all test cases. It uses standard library algorithms to do the work of removing duplicate ranks, binary search, etc.

Comment: Thanks Blastfurnace, then I'll go read about algorithms in C++